# Is there a clean way to get the current Gmail message ID?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail

I am writing a Chrome extension and I would like to be able to get the current Gmail message ID (in either conversation view or not).  I tried using the Gmail.js library but as mentioned here the observers quit firing after a while:

https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/issues/304?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

So is there a different solution?  I have searched around and do not see a clean, reliable solution.

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Comment: Try using gmail's hidden undocumented `gmonkey` API as shown in [this library](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/500-user-scripts-gmail-library/).

Comment: could be wrong, but isn't the message ID in the URL?

Comment: @Noam Hacker: Actually, I think that's the thread ID, which for a thread with a single message (or non-conversation view) is the same thing.  But for in conversation view that value does not change when opening/closing different messages in a thread.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Thanks for the pointer, but I just saw that it requires Greasemonkey (or similar library) to be installed.  Since this is for more than just me I don't think I can ask my users to install that.

Comment: It's just a javascript code, it doesn't require Greasemonkey. The point was that you can reuse the approach.